# rewrite rule of post when accessed from archives pages

Tags: url-rewriting, rewrite-rules

Im trying to rewrite the slug of the permalink of my post when accessed from my archives pages.

at the moment it display like:

www.mydomain.com/categorypost/post_title

id like instead

www.mydomain.com/archives/categorypost/post_title

but only when accessed from the archive pages, if i access the post from another page it should still be www.mydomain.com/categorypost/post_title

i'm really having a bad time with that . .

thank you for your time

Comment: Do you want two URLs for the same content? That sounds like bad idea. If you need where the use come from you should use other methods

Comment: Well,

what i'm looking to achieve is to have the permalink setup as www.mydomain.com/archives/categorypost/post_title
when I accessed it from the archives pages . . . If you know any other solution to achieve this, I'm more than in :)

Thank you for your time :)

Comment: Totally agree with @cybmeta You should really rethink your complete structure. Why would you even need a post to be accessible from two different URL's

Comment: hm,

What I need is to have a archive template, which I have create and works fine,

However I need to have the post accessed from the archive-page with a different slug . ..  request from my client :( :( It may not be great but is that He needs . ..  . Do you have any solution by any chance ? or step to guide me with something else to make this work ?

Comment: or the other solution I would need is to have a different single.php link to this archives.php . .  but using the database from all the post using the single.php . . . I need my post accessed from the archives.php to have a different layout than the post accessed from the other part of the website . ..

Comment: Stick with the structures available and make use of the `template_include` hook if you need to deviate. Look at the template hierarchy and learn how it works. Unfortunately how you handle this difficult client is up to you. In my opinion, you bought yourself a cat in a sack